# AutoHotKey keystroke break loop

Tags: loops, autohotkey, break

Using AutoHotKey, I have a rather simple loop script that I want to be able to break by the stroke of a key. I tried a few different codes from websites but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the code:

```
#g::
Loop 20
{
    MouseClick, left,  142,  542
    Sleep, 1000
    MouseClick, left,  138,  567
    Sleep, 1500
    MouseClick, left,  97,  538 
    Sleep, 1000
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a global variable (keepCycling) and toggle it to break the loop. Global variables should be declared in the beginning of a script.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a global variable might be the easiest solution for your case since your loop takes a while to complete.

```
global break_g = 0 

#b::
    break_g = 1 
return


#g::
break_g = 0
Loop 20
{
    MouseClick, left,  142,  542
    Sleep, 1000
    MouseClick, left,  138,  567
    Sleep, 1500
    MouseClick, left,  97,  538 
    Sleep, 1000
    if( break_g = 1)
    {
        return
    }
}
return ; also you were missing this return
```

Comment: this does work. thank you. A instantaneous halt would be the best but I'm satisfied with this.

Comment: @Dave Just put an if statement before every MouseClick.

Answer (score 1):

Toggling global variable is the way to go. You need to declare it in the beginning of the script.

global keep_working = 1  ; set break to off in the beginning of the script

b::   ; set break on
    keep_working = 0 
return

g::  ; set working to on and start the loop
keep_working = 1
Loop,             ; loop until b is pressed (was loop, 20  in original code)
{
    MouseClick, left,  142,  542
    Sleep, 1000
    MouseClick, left,  138,  567
    Sleep, 1500
    MouseClick, left,  97,  538 
    Sleep, 1000
    if( keep_working = 0)
    {
        return  ; required to stop execution
    }
}
return ; this delimiter is required at the end of hotkey procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
#g::  
Loop 20  
{  
    KeyWait,Ctrl,D T0  
        if Errorlevel = 0  
            break  
    MouseClick, left,  142,  542  
    KeyWait,Ctrl,D T0  
        if Errorlevel = 0  
            break  
    Sleep, 1000  
    KeyWait,Ctrl,D T0  
        if Errorlevel = 0  
            break  
    MouseClick, left,  138,  567  
    KeyWait,Ctrl,D T0  
        if Errorlevel = 0  
            break  
    Sleep, 1500  
    KeyWait,Ctrl,D T0  
        if Errorlevel = 0  
            break  
    MouseClick, left,  97,  538  
    KeyWait,Ctrl,D T0  
        if Errorlevel = 0  
            break  
    Sleep, 1000  
}  

return
```

Using the above can be helpful as the effect would be instantaneous. More often than not, you will have your loop stopped when you hold Ctrl for an interval.

Comment: You have flaws in your code. You have to hold ctrl for a the full duration of the sleep time if you start holding it when sleep is executed. So effect is far from instant. You also duplicated same command six-times, you should not repeat yourself (what if OP wants to change the hotkey, good luck doing that 6+ times). And you don't know if the whole loop is a single command that should not be interrupted; using my method you can still put an if statement(if you want, that is up to the user) whenever you want and achieve a termination of the loop.

Comment: @armin , I know that Sleep fact.(So I have used "more often than not") Also my answer was mostly question-specific and not for the general situation. (As dave's script is small, i can afford the repetition 6 times ).  and there is no need for that **break_g** being a "global" . I see you edited that point from my code.